# Even specifing "type":"module" in package.json for importing external file, still throwing SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I cannot find a solution for my problem. I use VS Code to code in JavaScript. I want to import an array of objects from an external file.
In my .js file I use this statement:

```
import {myarray} from './path/to/file.js'
```

I encounter the warning to add "type": "module" in the scripts section of my package.json file. After adding it, I still have the same warning with the error message:
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in your main .js file, importing what you want from the external file.

```
import { myarray } from "./path/to/file.mjs";
```

Then for your external file

```
export myarray = [];
```

Rename .js files to .mjs. Hopefully this works.